# Is there any known way to sum a subserie (square indices) of geometric series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

I was interested in the following sum. Although im not sure there exist any known way to sum this...it seems rather difficult. Can we sum for $0<r<1$

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}r^{k^2}= 1+r+r^4+r^{9}+r^{16}+\cdots ? $$

Maybe there exists a function $f$ that has a Taylor series: $f^{(n^2)}(0)=(n^2)!$ and $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for non-squares. It seems rather impossible, and im just grasping for ideas here.

Comment: It is an important kind of sum, and can be expressed in terms of the Jacobi theta function.

Comment: There _always_ exists a function (in fact many) that has a given formal series as its Taylor series. There might not however be any nice expression for such a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists a known function, Jacobi theta function, defined as

> $$
> \vartheta(z; \tau):=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty w^{n^2}\eta^n \tag1
> $$

where $w=:e^{\pi/\tau}$ and where $\eta:=e^{2i\pi z} $.

You may have a look at many [interesting properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function) of $\vartheta(\cdot;\cdot)$.

In particular, the Jacobi triple product tells us that for complex numbers $w$ and $q$ with $|q| < 1$ and $w ≠ 0$, we have

> $$
> \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty  w^{2n}q^{n^2}=\prod_{m=1}^\infty 
> \left( 1 - q^{2m}\right)
> \left( 1 + w^{2}q^{2m-1}\right)
> \left( 1 + w^{-2}q^{2m-1}\right).
> $$

The following related finite sum has a closed form due to Gauss ($1801$)

> $$
> \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\exp\left(\frac{2\pi{\rm i}n^2}N\right)=\begin{cases}(1+{\rm i})\sqrt N&{\rm if}\ N\equiv0\mod 4\\\sqrt N&{\rm if}\ N\equiv1\mod 4\\0&{\rm if}\ N\equiv2\mod 4\\{\rm i}\sqrt N&{\rm if}\ N\equiv3\mod 4.\end{cases}
> $$